# What is the minimum land ownership to become a king according to sastras?

Tags: mahabharata, smriti, kings

Pranam,
I heard that in Mahabharata Pandavas asked for 5 villages(one each for each brother) so that they can do their kshatriya duty(as kings)..
1)So can a person who has absolute power ower a village crown himself a king?
2)How many houses(minimum) constitute a village according to sastras?